# Can I manually fire a row deactivation with jQuery-menu-aim?

Tags: jquery

I'm using [jQuery-menu-aim](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim) for my navigation menu. I've run into a problem where expanded submenus will remain active when the menu is no longer being moused over. Here's my code, though the problem isn't easy to see here:

```
        $(".nav-section").menuAim({
             activate: function(row) {

                var $row = $(row)

                $(row).toggleClass("nav-active");
                var navItem = $(row).attr("data-nav-item");
                $(".nav-panel[data-nav-panel='" + navItem + "'").toggleClass("nav-panel-active");

             },
             deactivate: function(row) {
                $(".drop-nav").removeClass("first-hover");
                $(row).toggleClass("nav-active");

                var navItem = $(row).attr("data-nav-item");
                $panel = $("[data-nav-panel='" + navItem + "'")
                $panel.toggleClass("nav-panel-active");
             },

             enter: function() { },
             exit: function() { },
             exitMenu: function() { },
             rowSelector: "> li",
             submenuDirection: "right"
         });
```

Here is a Codepen that will show you what I'm talking about: http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/BNgzzG

Hover over the red menu and then hover over a menu item to expand the submenu. With the submenu visible, hover out of the menu completely. Then hover back over the red menu to show the menu again. You'll notice that whatever submenu was active before you left is still active. I'd like for the submenus to reset when the users mouse leaves the menu and it disappears.

I've tried using the following code to achieve that behavior, but it didn't work and instead I got a weird bug where more than one parent row would be highlighted.

```
        $( ".nav-browse-products" ).mouseleave(function() {

           $(".nav-active").toggleClass("nav-active");
           $(".nav-panel-active").toggleClass("nav-panel-active");

        });
```

The only idea I have for it not working with this extra code is that the row deactivation is not firing. And without that it'll keep the old row activated as well as a new row. I'm not really sure if there's a way to manually fire the row deactivation or not. I dug through the plugin but couldn't decipher a way to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i have face same issue so i am using https://github.com/banesto/jQuery-menu-aim/tree/994b7c96b8089c41aad1bfcd008d02b28208ada0 replace **kamens/jquery.menu-aim.js** to **banesto/jquery.menu-aim.js** and options it works